# Can we make a particular function call required/necessary in another function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

- I have the ngOnInit function from the Angular life-cycle hooks which gets called after the component is created.
  I want to make a function call mandatory inside this ngOnInit function to enable some basic functionalities.
- Like an interface that we can implement on a class and tell typescript which methods would be mandatory, i need a similar solution for making function calls inside a function to be mandatory.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.setPermissions('ABC'); // Make this function call mandatory
}
```

Comment: Not really possible .. you could have an abstract class and define `ngOnInit` in there and make the required calls, and have your subclasses implement an abstract method that is also called in `ngOnInit`..

Comment: Using an Abstract Class with an Abstract method would again work same as the interface OnInit in angular where it would only ask for the required ngOnInit function but not the inner function call!

Comment: I think code can say what I mean better: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8AoBChAOwHMB5KgSSoEtEAKAShPMr4gAWLMADoAtgFdIeYMmRcA3AHolCMcCoATYBAD2UAJ5JZyXnwqDhIqDkh0AZrQbM2iswgC+7ydJNcSXnygkDDwCDZ2jvRMrBBcAFwIAG66LJoKpF6kKGgYAMoSIAS5CDgAHhA4WhjYYPiEYGR8ERAOTjGu3E3mFCpq+jgIkBL29u5eHkA